# How to activate Text-To-Speech when clicked on TextView?

Tags: android, onclick, text-to-speech, textview

the question is as above.

scenario : i programmatically created table rows with text view in it. i wanted to allow text-to-speech when i clicked on the textview. there is some reason for not using listview. i tried to use button for easier usage, however the button that i created is always out of the dimension that gave. so, i wanted to use textview to activate the TTS.

how do i do that ?

i tried using

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        String speech = list.get(i).toString();
        tts.speak(speech,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    }
});
```

i uses for-loop for it, so that it will create a table row for every data collected. the problem is, it requested the "i" to be final. and when i made it final, i cant use i++.

please help. thanks alot =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare your `int i;` in your class. I believe this will help you to avoid of using final modifier.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

int i;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...
         tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
             {
               public void OnClick(View v){
                  String speech = list.get(i).toString();
                  tts.speak(speech,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
               }
         });
         ...
     }


}
```

or put this code `String speech = list.get(i).toString();
                  tts.speak(speech,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);` to another method. for example:

```
 tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
    public void OnClick(View v){
       speak();
    }
  });
```

__

```
public void speak(){
   String speech = list.get(i).toString();
   tts.speak(speech,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
}
```